# Man-in-the-middle proxy without any certificate errors?

Tags: networking, proxy, ssl, certificate

I am working in school as IT engineer. We have legal order from our governmental ISP to collect logs about our users network behavior, to identify infected PC's and so on.

I need to filter all traffic, well most of it - 80 and 443 ports.

I know how to filter 80 port, but how do I filter SSL traffic without throwing errors in client browser without fiddling with students devices?

I have access to DigiCert certificates which I can get. Would it help to have real certificate from trusted CA not to throw any errors?

Objective is to have transparent logging proxy with SSO (AD), without need to install certificates to computers, without setting proxy in PC, without any errors.

Comment: *without throwing errors in client browser without fiddling with students devices* Not possible, you will have to install your 'intermediate' certs into their browsers (OS).

Comment: Even real, trusted certificates won't help? Because we have BYOD policy, and need to make it secure.

Comment: This would effectively break the security of the entire internet by allowing your ISP or anyone who can feed you through their proxy by whatever means to do whatever they like to you, I would sincerely hope that this is not possible.

Comment: I hope you understand, that we want effectively identify people who are browsing illegal sites as we are educational institution and our ISP is governmental/academic institution. And we are getting complaints about attacks from our IP to some random websites.

Comment: @ŽygimantasMarkevičius Everyone understands your concern about the user behaviour and your need to protect your network. Now you should understand that it is your own requirement "*without need to install certificates to computers, without setting proxy in PC, without any errors*" that makes it impossible to fulfill.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I filter SSL traffic without throwing errors in client browser without fiddling with students devices?

Fortunately you cannot!

Because if you could, anyone could and there would be no internet as we know it.

> Would it help to have real certificate from trusted CA not to throw any errors?

No, it would not, because DigiCert would sign a certificate for the domain which you have and can prove ownership of (and they would verify it).

This certificate could then be used to protect the transmission between any browser and your school server (accessible using the domain for which it was issued) without the fear that some IT engineer somewhere is intercepting the communication "*without the need to install certificates to computers, without setting proxy in PC, without any errors*".

---

To rephrase: HTTPS inspection is possible, but it **requires** installing a root certificate on client machines.

Refer for example to Microsoft's TechNet article [How HTTPS inspection works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658156.aspx) (mind the word "because" below):

> Because the HTTPS inspection certificate was previously placed in the client computer’s Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store, the computer trusts any certificate that is signed by this certificate.

However the condition you included in your question:

> without need to install certificates to computers, without setting proxy in PC, without any errors

determines the answer: **you cannot achieve that**.

Comment: What would be effective solution for BYOD website filtering (http and https) and logging without need to do anything with students devices?

Comment: Again: fortunately for TLS **there is nothing you can do** if students themselves do not allow you to spy on them by installing your root certificate on their devices. You can block DNS requests, but it can be circumvented by using DNSCrypt. Or you can block the whole traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Using certificates would require you to create at least one certificate per website accesed by your users (certificates contain the domain name). DigiCert seems to be installed (in Windows at least) as a trusted root CA so that *could* work, and would need verification on non-windows computers.

---

However, I would recommend that you re-evaluate what has been asked of you. Do they really ask you to log the *entire payload* of the traffic? That represents an astronomical quantity of data, even for small entities.

I'm a college student, and in my college all Internet connections are logged, but they only log what IP I connect to, what protocols I use etc. They don't collect the actual payload, we have about 10k users on-site 24/7... And they don't use impersonation as far as I know, because it's useless in this case.

Only collecting this kind of metadata would not require to MITM, you just need to analyse the data that comes through your router. Even on a secure connection, destination IP and ports are not encrypted. You can also intercept DNS lookups (not encrypted, on port 53 IIRC) to cross-reference that with used IPs.

---

**EDIT** to respond to comments:

1. Compliants about attcks: that's the main purpose of logging in my college's network: once they get the complaint, they can tell which user did it.
2. Blocking illegal sites: you can do so on the default DNS used by computers that conenct to your network to block domain names. Also, you can use the firewall to blacklist outbound traffic these sites' IPs.
3. Proxy: that's independent of the notion of certificates. You're gonna need the certificate only if your proxy impersonates the website, and it will do so if you want to decrypt or modify the payload itself. Depending on what is actually requested, this may not be needed. A proxy that just forwards trafic, even if it logs it, does not need to impersonate the website
4. Authentication: goes with the proxy, and you can use it to cross-reference your users' indentity with what they do.
5. "One certificate per website": the digital certificates usually contain the website's name, which means you can't use the same certificate to impersonate several different websites. Otherwise, the user will see a big red warning "This connection is insecure" whenever they try to HTTPS to a website.

Comment: Sometimes we get complaints about attacks from our network. Also, we need to block illegal betting sites, and some other entertainment websites like illegal movie pages and so on.

Comment: Also, we want to implement authentication to proxy via AD and SSO for domain PC's. So I believe all traffic needs to to be filtered?

Comment: _Using certificates would require you to create at least one certificate per website accesed by your users_ - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I made an edit to answer your comments

Comment: What about firewalling DNS queries from devices except internal DNS server? Would that be kinda solution?

Comment: That would prevent your users from using external DNSs (Google's one or OpenDNS for instance), so you control which *domain name* they access (i.e. the name of the website). However, if there are some *really* tech savvy users, they might (although very unlikely) know the IP of the website they try to reach, so you should also filter IPs (just to be on the safe side). Just run `nslookup bannedsite.com` to find the IP of a banned domain name.